# reactjs pass a prop and use it as array index

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass a prop that is a number, and use it to define an array index to find image src in an array.

I have this in state

```
  imgno: [1]
```

(not sure if this should be like this)

```
  imgno: 1
```

I'm passing this as a prop to a component and I want to use it here

```
<img src={props.slike[{props.imgno}]} alt="slika" />
```

but it's not working

if there is a different solution I'm ready to listen :)

Comment: Can you provide a bit of context for that line of code?

Comment: You only need `{}` to embed JS expressions in JSX elements.  Inside a JS expression, you must write normal JS.

Comment: I take it `slike` is the array you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the item at index `props.imgno` of the array `props.slike` you simply do:

```
<img src={props.slike[props.imgno]} alt="slika" />
```